# XML parsing (SAX,StAX) vs Scanner

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

The question is not related to comparison between different parsers, but it's related to the memory utilization and usage.

My question is that which method is better to read exactly one line "two elements" of an XML file, the XML parsers or Scanner method?

I will be running this script only once through 30 GB of XML files, so I thought of Scanner assuming it will be a faster method than xml parsing since I'm only reading certain lines from each object without manipulation or what so ever.

Comment: 30GB is that a single file or a lot of smaller files?

Comment: smaller files some of them approx around 1.0 GB to 1.5 GB - thanks

Answer (score 2):

The speed is more than likely restricted by the speed of reading 30 GB of data, so either way of parsing will work.  SAX is very efficient and can read XML's as a stream, so memory usage should be low.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
So let's say that I've 30 files each of 1 GB, will XML parsing (SAX) will be faster than scanner? 
Thank you :)

Comment: Scanner might be slightly faster in pure CPU time, but it won't affect the time taken as both solutions will need to read 30 GB of data which is far more likely to be the bottleneck.  In other words, the parsers can handle data faster than your storage solution can likely deliver it.